# Question related to the following function $f\left( x \right) = \frac{{b - x}}{{1 - bx}}$

Tags: functions

Let $f:\left( {0,1} \right) \to R$ be defined by $f\left( x \right) = \frac{{b - x}}{{1 - bx}}$
, where 'b' is a constant such that $0 < b < 1$. Then

(A) $f$ is not invertible on (0,1)

(B) $f\ne f^{-1}$ on (0,1)and $f'(b)=\frac{1}{f'(0)}$

(C) $f= f^{-1}$ on (0,1)and $f'(b)=\frac{1}{f'(0)}$

(D) $f^{-1}$ is differentiable on (0,1)

My approach is as follow

$f:\left( {0,1} \right) \to R$, $f\left( x \right) = \frac{{b - x}}{{1 - bx}}$,$0 < b < 1$

$f'\left( x \right) = \frac{{\left( {1 - bx} \right)\frac{d}{{dx}}\left( {b - x} \right) - \left( {b - x} \right)\frac{d}{{dx}}\left( {1 - bx} \right)}}{{{{\left( {1 - bx} \right)}^2}}}$

$f'\left( x \right) = \frac{{\left( {1 - bx} \right) \times  - 1 - \left( {b - x} \right) \times \left( { - b} \right)}}{{{{\left( {1 - bx} \right)}^2}}} = \frac{{\left( {1 - bx} \right) \times  - 1 + \left( {b - x} \right) \times b}}{{{{\left( {1 - bx} \right)}^2}}} = \frac{{\left( { - 1 + bx} \right) + \left( {{b^2} - bx} \right)}}{{{{\left( {1 - bx} \right)}^2}}} = \frac{{{b^2} - 1}}{{{{\left( {1 - bx} \right)}^2}}}$

$x\in(0,1)$ and $b\in(0,1)$, then $bx\in(0,1)$, hence $f'(x)<0$, hence my assumption is that $f$ is invertible as it is decreasing function when $0<x<1$ but official answer is (A) that is **$f$ is not invertible on (0,1)**

Comment: I think you are right and the official answer is wrong. You don't need take the derivative to prove this. $f(x)=f(y) \implies (x-y)(b^2-1)=0 \implies x=y$.

Comment: The function is NOT surjective. What is the preimage of 1? So, it should not be invertible.

Answer (score 1):

Just observe that there is no $x$ such that $f(x) =\frac{1}{b}$. If any such $x$ exists then it would imply that $b^2=1$ which is certainly not possible. This shows that $f$ is not surjective which implies that $f$ is not invertible.

Edit:
One more way to see that $f$ is not surjective is to observe that $-1 < f(x) < b$ by simply manipulating the inequalites $0<x<1$ and $0<b<1$.

Comment: This is a multiple choice question with official answer (A)

Comment: B,C and D are incorrect. This was a question asked in IIT-JEE 2011-paper2

Comment: My answer shows that $f^{-1}$ is not a function. So all other options are trivially wrong

Comment: can you elaborate it clearly

Comment: I edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

You also may show that $f(f(x))=x$.